# Getdate Function details

Tags: getdate

Curious to know the differences on how Getdate() is working with respect to SSIS and SQL Server. Is it possible to get the implementation details/Code of Getdate() function for SSIS and SQL Server.

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/getdate-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks it helps. Documentation shows "Returns the current date of the system". But I want to know how the system date is retrieved. Implementation or built in code that shows how it retrieves the system date.